# column B in sheet two equals column B in sheet one, if Column A is sheet two is equal to any value in Column A in sheet one

Tags: worksheet-function

I have two excel sheets. They are formatted the same.  Would you please show me the formula to figure out column B value if Column A in Sheet B match any value in Column A in Sheet A?

**Sheet A**

```
Column A        Column B
Customer A      $1.25   
Customer B      $1.00  
Customer C      $0.75
```

**Sheet B**

```
Column A        Column B
Customer E      ?  
Customer B      ? 
Customer A      ?
```

Answer (score 1):

`VLOOKUP` is what you need to look at.

in cell B1 on sheet B, the formula `=VLOOKUP(A1,SheetA!A1:B3,2,FALSE)` would get you your data.

the four parameters for the function are:

1. What data you are looking for
2. Where to look for the item referenced in part 1
3. What column from the data to return
4. If an exact match is needed (no sorting required), or close value will do (sorting required)
   *`False` = exact match*